# $ in credentials binding + sh escaping madness for declarative pipelines

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

This is my password: "ASD123$567"

This doesn't work

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'creds',
    usernameVariable: 'myuser', passwordVariable: 'mypass')]) {
    sh "some command --username ${myuser} --password ${mypass}"
}
```

What i see in the output is mypass is not obfuscated and most importantly it looks like its getting cut off after the "$" so its only showing ASD123

Edit: I was a little confused about where this was breaking down, looks like it was actually translating to the Shell step specifically was causing the issue.

Comment: how is that a solution? this is a known issue and $$ works?

Comment: Can you try -password "\"$mypass\""?

Comment: that seems to fail the pipeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the credentials function:

```
pipeline {
  ...
  stage("Credentials") {
    environment {
      MY_CREDENTIAL = credentials('creds')
    }
    steps {
      // Single quotes!
      sh 'echo ${MY_CREDENTIAL}'
      sh 'echo ${MY_CREDENTIAL_USR}:${MY_CREDENTIAL_PSW}'
    }
  }
}
```

For further info, have a look at https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-model-definition-plugin/wiki/Environment-variables

Comment: Wow, They need to update their docs, I didn't think it supported the usernamepassword binding

Comment: totally works, also it seems I could inject the groovy var as long as I wrap it in `"echo '${myVarWithdollar}'"` for bash to know its a literal string

Answer (score 2):

My solution (if you want to call it that):

```
--password  ${mypass.replaceAll('\\$','\\\\\\$')}
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with the same issue executing some remote ssh scripts without `sshagent`. My password has several $ in it and needs to be entered as a parameter to `mysql -p`

The accepted solution did not work for me since none of the dollars was escapted when I passed them. 
I finally solved it using a combination of both suggested solutions `${mypass.replaceAll('\\$','\\\\\\$')}`

```
pipeline {
  ...
  stage("Credentials") {
    environment {
      MY_CREDENTIAL = credentials('creds')
    }
    steps {
      // Single quotes!
      sh """ 
          ssh user@server "
               mysqldump -u${MY_CREDENTIAL_USR} -p'${MY_CREDENTIAL_PSW.replaceAll('\$','\\\$')}' DBNAME > dump.sql
          "
         """
    }
  }
}
```